# Requests: How to access a session that was initiated by the user from the backend?

Tags: python, http, session, cookies, browser

I'm working in a little project that scrapes a website but to scrape the content I need to be logged in as a user. This website only provides Facebook login as authentication method.

My app will prompt the user to login in the mentioned website and after that my program goes in and makes the scraping of the specific content I'm looking to extract.

So in other words the user initiates the session in their browser but I need that session to persist to my backend so I can access the section of the website that is only accesible after you login.

I'm a bit lost here. I don't know what is the best way to achieve this. Any ideas?

Best!